# LESS doesn't work at localhost Linux

Tags: php, css, linux, less, localhost

I want to use LESS, but it is doesn't work at my localhost.

Here is my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
  <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my styles.less

```
@nice-blue: #5B83AD;

body{
backgroud-color: @nice-blue;
}
```

[image: And here is my page and firebug]

Comment: It just looks like `body` in your HTML has 0px width/height hence you can't see its background.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using your less files directly in your HTML. Less is a CSS pre-processor, and needs to be compiled in order to be read by your browser.

Follow the examples here (http://lesscss.org/) on how to compile your LESS file so that you can use the CSS.

Comment: There is a Client-side usage for development. It is excactly what I want.